# Zend Framework2 Form Errors Array To JSON

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, zend-framework2

I'm receiving this array from zend form

```
Array
(
    [user] => Array
        (
            [firstName] => Array
                (
                    [isEmpty] => Please enter First Name
                )

            [lastName] => Array
                (
                    [isEmpty] => Please enter Last Name
                )

            [password] => Array
                (
                    [isEmpty] => Please enter Password
                )

            [confirmPassword] => Array
                (
                    [isEmpty] => Please enter Confirm Password
                )

            [email] => Array
                (
                    [isEmpty] => Please enter Email Address
                )

            [gender] => Array
                (
                    [notInArray] => Gender must be Male OR Female
                    [isEmpty] => Please select your gender
                )

            [phone] => Array
                (
                    [isEmpty] => Value is required and can't be empty
                )

            [birthDate] => Array
                (
                    [isEmpty] => Please enter Birth Date
                )

            [country] => Array
                (
                    [id] => Array
                        (
                            [isEmpty] => Please select Country
                        )

                )

            [userGroup] => Array
                (
                    [id] => Array
                        (
                            [isEmpty] => Please select User Group
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

and I want this array to be converted into the following array:

```
Array
(
    [user[firstName]] => [{"Please enter First Name"}]
    [user[lastName]] => [{"Please enter Last Name"}]

    ...........

    [user[gender]] => [{"Gender must be Male OR Female","Please select your gender"}]

    ..............
    [user[country][id]] => [{"Please select Country"}]
)
```

I tried the following code but It didn't work

```
$errors = $form->getMessages();
                $newErrors = array();
                foreach ($errors as $key => $value) {
                    $elementName = $key;
                    if(is_array($value)) {
                        foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
                            $elementName .= $k;
                            if(!is_array($v)) {
                                $message = $v;
                                $newErrors[$elementName] = json_encode($v);
                            } else {
                                foreach ($v as $ke => $va) {
                                    $elementName .= $ke;
                                    if(!is_array($va)) {
                                        $newErrors[$elementName] = json_encode($va);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: You may want to elaborate on your use case, why do you need the errors in JSON? Are you posting a form via AJAX and want to apply some error styling on the form?

Comment: Yes absolutely, I'm validating the form with ajax and need the json response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To directly answer your question.

This has not been tested, although I believe it should work.

```
public function formatElementErrors(FieldsetInterface $collection, array $data, $parent = null)
{
    $results = [];

    foreach($data as $name => $errors) {

        if (! $collection->has($name) || ! is_array($errors)) {
            continue;
        }

        $element = $collection->get($name);

        $name = isset($parent) ? sprintf('%s[%s]', $parent, $name) : $name;

        if ($element instanceof FieldsetInterface) {

            $results = array_merge(
                $results,
                $this->formatElementErrors($element, $errors, $name)
            );

        } else {
            if (! isset($results[$name])) $results[$name] = [];

            foreach($errors as $message) {
                $results[$name][] = $message;
            }
        }
    }
    return $results;
}

$errors = $this->formatElementErrors($form, $errors);
```

Comment: You're almost there but it is giving [country[id]] instead of user[country[id]].. can we fix it?

Comment: I think that should solve it, i'll try and test it when I have a chance.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is possible, rather than retrieve a JSON array with the errors of the form, I opt to return the entire form HTML pre-rendered (including the error styles etc).

I can see that your attempt to re-key the result array is because the form elements, when nested, are given a new name; meaning you need some messy JS code to search the DOM for theses elements and add the relevant styles.

With my solution we use the standard view rendering (meaning the normal ZF2 view helpers) to apply the errors.

For example

```
// We are creating something
public function createAction()
{
    $serviceManager = $this->getServiceLocator();
    $formElementManager = $serviceManager->get('FormElementManager');

    $form = $this->formElementManager->get('MyModule\Form\SomeCreateForm');

    $request = $this->getRequest();

    $view = new ViewModel(compact('form'));

    if ($request->isPost()) {

        $form->setData($request->getPost());

        if ($form->isValid()) {

            // handle form success

        } else if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {

            // The form data was posted via ajax and is invalid

            // Set the view template to a view that just renders the form
            //
            // For example, the script would include:
            //
            // <?php echo $this->form($form);
            //
            $view->setTempalte('my/view-template/form');

            // Now render the view, using the view renderer
            $content = $serviceManager->get('ViewRenderer')->renderer($view);

            return new JsonModel([
                'success' => false, // flag for us to know we have an error in JS
                'content' => $content // The HTML content of the form, including the errors
            ]);
        }
    }

    $view->setTempalte('my/view-template/create');

    return $view;
}
```

To expand on this, you can also create a controller plugin 'JsonModel' to encapsulate this. If you pass in a `Zend\View\Model\ViewModel` as the 'content' key the plugin would then handle the rendering of it

The controller code would then become allot cleaner

```
return $this->jsonModel([
    'content' => $view
]);
```

Comment: I don't want this because I just want to get the json error response as I asked for because HTML is too heavy for ajax response.

Comment: I can easily get user[firstName] or user[country][id] input fields in jquery and can set the error messages by javascript.

Comment: I have yet to see any issues with performance using this method; although the response will be larger and therefore slower; in real world terms the difference is negligible (it's just text). This decision of course will depend entirely on your requirements and preferences. Personally, I would always opt for the cleaner code solution as it helps with maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

Following code convert the array to required format. But first what you want as output is mix of json & php array that should not be done. Instead convert into an php array then do json encode.

```
$data = array(); 
foreach($arr['user'] as $key => $item)
{
    foreach($item as $key1 => $item1)
    {
        if(is_array($item1))
        {
            list($key2, $item2) = each($item1);
            $data['user'][$key][$key1] = $item2;
        }
        else
        {
            $data['user'][$key] = $item1;
        }                   
    }               
}
print_r($data);
echo json_encode($data);
```

Array Output is

```
Array
(
    [user] => Array
        (
            [firstName] => Please enter First Name
            [lastName] => Please enter Last Name
            [password] => Please enter Password
            [confirmPassword] => Please enter Confirm Password
            [email] => Please enter Email Address
            [gender] => Please select your gender
            [phone] => Value is required and can't be empty
            [birthDate] => Please enter Birth Date
            [country] => Array
                (
                    [id] => Please select Country
                )

            [userGroup] => Array
                (
                    [id] => Please select User Group
                )

        )

)
```

While applying json_encodereturn following json string.

```
{
  "user": {
    "firstName": "Please enter First Name",
    "lastName": "Please enter Last Name",
    "password": "Please enter Password",
    "confirmPassword": "Please enter Confirm Password",
    "email": "Please enter Email Address",
    "gender": "Please select your gender",
    "phone": "Value is required and can't be empty",
    "birthDate": "Please enter Birth Date",
    "country": {
      "id": "Please select Country"
    },
    "userGroup": {
      "id": "Please select User Group"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you seen, what I wanted exactly??

Comment: Yes and I added already in my asnwer at top. That what this is not the exactly same way you want it. But could be a better way to send json to javascript from php.